# Joomla importer merger structure only merges first table mentioned in schema

Tags: joomla-3.x

Joomla importer merger structure only merges the first table mentioned in schema.

Try this:

```
$importer = new JDatabaseImporterMysqli();
$database = JFactory::getDBO();
$importer->setDbo($database);
$filename = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'components' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'com_dtsms' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'schema' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'schema.xml';
$importer->from(file_get_contents($filename));

$importer->mergeStructure();
```

Sample XML:

```
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <database name="">
  <table_structure name="#__dtsms_answer_settings">
   <field Field="id" Type="bigint(7)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="auto_increment" />
   <field Field="name" Type="varchar(10)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="description" Type="varchar(256)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="setting" Type="text" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="state" Type="tinyint(1)" Null="YES" Key="" Default="0" Extra="" />
   <field Field="ordering" Type="bigint(7)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="modified" Type="datetime" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="creator" Type="bigint(7)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="default" Type="tinyint(1)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="created" Type="datetime" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <key Table="#__dtsms_answer_settings" Non_unique="0" Key_name="PRIMARY" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="id" Collation="A" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" />
  </table_structure>
  <table_structure name="#__dtsms_lists">
   <field Field="id" Type="bigint(7)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="auto_increment" />
   <field Field="name" Type="varchar(100)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="created" Type="datetime" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="modified" Type="datetime" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="createdby" Type="bigint(7)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="dtreg_event_id" Type="binary(7)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="ordering" Type="int(7)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="state" Type="tinyint(1)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <key Table="#__dtsms_lists" Non_unique="0" Key_name="PRIMARY" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="id" Collation="A" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" />
  </table_structure>
  <table_structure name="#__dtsms_log_entries">
   <field Field="priority" Type="int(11)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="message" Type="varchar(512)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="date" Type="datetime" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="category" Type="varchar(255)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="user_id" Type="bigint(7)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
   <field Field="recipient_id" Type="bigint(7)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" />
  </table_structure>
```

The expected result is to merge all table structures. But it only merges `#__dtsms_answer_settings`.

Comment: Your sample xml didn't make it into the question. Can we check the syntax/contents of your xml file? I've never used this feature, but you may need to divide and conquer -- by converting the xml data into an array of table structures and making iterated method calls.  As an aside, you might condense your filename creation by imploding an array of path values with the directory separator.  When you edit to include your xml, please shift your code block a bit to the left. Please also check for errors messages too.

Comment: I've been researching (for curiosity's sake) and I can't find any example scripts in the wild.  I did read that `from()` takes a mixed type parameter.  Perhaps you could use `xpath() to split your xml and iterate your multi-table xml data.

Comment: @mickmackusa: The XML was included, it just wasn't formatted properly. I have suggested an edit to fix this.

Comment: Check the Markdown version of my [edit suggestion](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9912) - I've only added whitespace. The entire XML was invisible due to poor formatting.

Comment: @mickmackusa: FYI: The edit has now been approved and the XML is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply , i fixed it . Issue in file libraries/joomla/database/importer.php. extended it and override the function "mergeStructure" . It is working fine now .Below is code .  Markup was just sample not full .

```
public function mergeStructure() {
    $prefix = $this->db->getPrefix();
    $tables = $this->db->getTableList();

    if ($this->from instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
        $xml = $this->from;
    } else {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($this->from);
    }

    // Get all the table definitions.
    $xmlTables = $xml->xpath('database/table_structure');

    foreach ($xmlTables as $table) {
        // Convert the magic prefix into the real table name.
        $tableName = (string) $table['name'];
        $tableName = preg_replace('|^#__|', $prefix, $tableName);

        if (in_array($tableName, $tables)) {
            // The table already exists. Now check if there is any difference.
            if ($queries = $this->getAlterTableSql($table)) {
                // Run the queries to upgrade the data structure.
                foreach ($queries as $query) {
                    $this->db->setQuery((string) $query);
                    $this->db->execute();
                }
            }
        } else {
            // This is a new table.
            $sql = $this->xmlToCreate($table);

            $this->db->setQuery((string) $sql);
            $this->db->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The trouble appears to be in your xml markup.  You have not closed your `<mysqldump>` or `<database>` tags.

While running diagnostics, I've revealed this list of errors:

[image]

Furthermore, because you are calling `setDbo()` you don't even need to include the `<database>` tag(s).

So I recommend altering the xml file in the following ways:

1. Remove `<database name="">`
2. Add `</mysqldump>`

If the "horse has already bolted" and you can't / don't want to adjust the .xml file(s), then you can merely append `."\n </database>\n</mysqldump>"` to the end of the value returned by `file_get_contents()`.

Here is a comprehensive snippet to help you and future researchers to diagnose issues with this type of task:

```
$crumbs = [JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, 'components', 'com_dtsms', 'lib', 'schema', 'schema.xml'];
$filename = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $crumbs);
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "<div class='bg-danger'>Could not find schema.xml file @ \"$filename\"</div>";
} elseif (($xml = file_get_contents($filename)) === false) {
    echo "<div class='bg-danger'>Failed to read XML file</div>";
} else {
    $xml .= "\n </database>\n</mysqldump>";  // patch invalid xml
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    if ($sxml === false) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>Invalid XML structure:";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $i => $error) {
            echo "<li> {$error->message}</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></div>";
    } else {
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->loadXML($xml);
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>"
            echo "XML Content:<br>";
            echo "<pre>" , htmlspecialchars($xml) , "</pre>";
        echo "</div>";
        try {
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $importer = new JDatabaseImporterMysqli();
            $importer->setDbo($db);  // database tag in xml will not be used
            $importer->from($xml);
            $importer->mergeStructure();
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>XML Data Successfully Merged</div>";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Never show exact error message when your application is live/public!
            echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>" , $e->getMessage() , "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you were getting "false positive" success signals on the first table.  I was not able to replicate success on only the first table.  If you don't mind, please explain (via comment or question edit) exactly how and why you are employing this operation in your project.  It has a few of us in the office scratching our head as to why you are using it.

Comment: Hi ,
    I have too many database fields updated in component . So instead of adding too many alter statement . First export mysql structure dump using joomla export lib . Then while using import to merge structure find this bug .

Comment: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/22660   . Here are details . I post the fix on github too . it is approved . Thanks all